# how to get grant access to excel file using python

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I want to open excel files, take a range and copy it into the file, new range is under prevision. Below code in python, but for every file I receive a dialog window in which I have to grant access to the file. What should I do to avoid it?

I gave permission to disk for application (anaconda, python, Excel, XlWings), it's not helping.

```
import os
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd

def main():
    source = ['/Users/username/Documents/work/out/out']
    target_wb = xw.Book('/Volumes/Transend_Mac/Coding/Py/        Скрипты/Work_UZ/Target/Target.xlsx')
    target_sh = target_wb.sheets[0]
    iRow = 1
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source[0]): # Список всех файлов и папок в директории folder
    for file in files:
        if (os.path.splitext(file)[1]=='.xlsx' or os.path.splitext(file)[1]=='.xls'): 
            source_wb = xw.Book(root+'/'+file,read_only=True,ignore_read_only_recommended=True)
            source_sh = source_wb.sheets.active
            sheet_name=source_sh.name
            source_wb.close()
            pdd=pd.read_excel(root+'/'+file, sheet_name)

            #вычсляем кол-во строк в таблице
            lenPdd = len(pdd.index)+1

            #получаем id заявки
            sRoot=str(root)
            sIdPi=sRoot[sRoot.rfind('/')+1:]

            #создаем столбец с номером id заявки
            list_IdPi = [sIdPi for i in range(0,lenPdd-1)]
            pdd['Pi_id']=list_IdPi
            #pdd1=pdd.append(list_IdPi)
            print('A'+str(iRow))
            target_sh.range('A'+str(iRow)).options(index = False).value = pdd
            iRow=iRow+lenPdd

        else:     
            print (root+'/'+file)

    target_wb.save()
    target_wb.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: ran it with `sudo`?

Comment: Is the file is already open in Excel? Excel seems to lock files it has open so close Excel then try again.

Comment: files are not open. there are about 300 files.

Comment: I use Anaconda, Spyder

Comment: I use this command and it's not help: sudo /Users/andreyandreev/opt/anaconda3/bin/python.app /Users/andreyandreev/Documents/python/Скрипты/CopySheetsInOneXlsx.py

Comment: You probably see this issue: https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/1262 open Spyder via terminal to work around it.

Comment: I see OSERROR: -50  If I press "Cancel"

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I also faced this issue when I tried to use xlwings to open the Excel file, while I had authorised my python IDE, Excel, Anaconda, and terminal with full disk access. As I used Mac OS, here I provided an alternative solution: **changing the permission setting of Excel file**.

As the system asked for granting toward the Excel file, I guess maybe the problem is that the Excel file did not authorise others to edit it directly; I just tried to right-click the Excel file (`Target.xlsx` in your case), go to the info, and change the permission of "everyone" to "Read & Write" instead.

I am not sure if my guess is correct or not. Even if I do it, it seems that "sometimes" the system still asked me to grant access to the Excel file, but at least sometimes it did not.

Hope that it could be helpful & others who face this issue could share your thought.